# $.grep not working with me for filtering JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to use grep so that I do not do multiple calls to my server for the controls it creates -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../WebMethods/MarketPersuitMethods.aspx/GetQueryInfo",
    data: '{Status: "' + Name + '", search: "' + SearchBox.text() + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (d) {
        var preparse = JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(d.d));
                    
        var data = $.grep(preparse, function (element, index) {
            return element.status.trim() == "Pending";
        });
        $("[id*=TextBox2]").text(preparse);
    }
});
```

This is returning JSON formatted data if I test the `preparse` variable.

I can't post the JSON because it's so much and would need to be anonymoized.  However as a sample it returns something like the following:

```
[{
    "Project ID": "18180",
    "OPRN": null,
    "Proj_Type": "2049",
    "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
    "SQFT": 2000,
    "State": "FL      ",
    "County": "Orange",
    "status": "Pending"
},
{
    "Project ID": "18180",
    "OPRN": null,
    "Proj_Type": "2049",
    "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
    "SQFT": 2000,
    "State": "SC",
    "County": "Orange",
    "status": "Pending"
},
{
    "Project ID": "18180",
    "OPRN": null,
    "Proj_Type": "2049",
    "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
    "SQFT": 2000,
    "State": "GA",
    "County": "Orange",
     "status": "Won"
}];
```

However, when trying to to `$.grep` I get the following with the `data` variable:

```
[{
    {
        "P,r,o,j,e,c,t, ,I,D,",:, ",1,8,1,8,0,",
        ",O,P,R,N,",:, ,n,u,l,l,
        "P,r,o,j,_,T,y,p,e,",:, ,",2,0,4,9,",
        "C,o,m,p,l,e,t,e,D,a,t,e,",:, ,",2,0,2,0,-,0,5,-,2,1,T,0,0,:,0,0,:,0,0,",
        ",S,Q,F,T,",:, ,2,0,0,0,,
        "S,t,a,t,e,",:, ,",G,A,",
        "C,o,u,n,t,y,",:, ,",O,r,a,n,g,e,",
         "s,t,a,t,u,s,": ",W,o,n,,
    }];
```

Comment: `var preparse = JSON.stringify(...` creates a string, so you're trying to grep on a string.  Are you sure you know what JSON is?

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` tells jquery that your server returns json and that jquery should convert it to an `object` for you - so `d` is a javascript object.  You then parse `d.d` as if it's json - , which will give you another javascript object which you then convert *back* to json - so your service is creating an object, convert it to a json string then adding it to the return value as property "d".  Why not just return a single json string from your service and use `$.grep(d.d, ...)`?   As it is, from your code, you *probably* just want to change to `var preparse = $.parseJSON(d.d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you don't need to do any preparsing or any preparation of your response at all.  The sample you've provided is JSON, and your AJAX code tells JS to expect a JSON response (`dataType: 'json'`), so in your `success` callback `d` is already JSON.  Simply get rid of your preparsing stuff, and your code works:

```js
let d = [
    {
        "Project ID": "18180",
        "OPRN": null,
        "Proj_Type": "2049",
        "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
        "SQFT": 2000,
        "State": "FL      ",
        "County": "Orange",
        "status": "Pending"
    },
    {
        "Project ID": "18180",
        "OPRN": null,
        "Proj_Type": "2049",
        "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
        "SQFT": 2000,
        "State": "SC",
        "County": "Orange",
        "status": "Pending"
    },
    {
        "Project ID": "18180",
        "OPRN": null,
        "Proj_Type": "2049",
        "CompleteDate": "2020-05-21T00:00:00",
        "SQFT": 2000,
        "State": "GA",
        "County": "Orange",
        "status": "Won"
    }
];

var data = $.grep(d, function (element, index) {
    return element.status.trim() == "Pending";
});

console.dir(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```